# Executing a sql query using ssis programmatically

Tags: c#, ssis, dts

I am working on writing a program to generate SSIS package which executes a query on multiple databases. I have already accomplished the task using a stored procedure however I don't want to use it. I have been struggling with Dts.runtime. I am using C#.

I have to read the query directly from the program and execute it, maybe using ExecuteSQLTask.Execute method. I am totally stuck, or it could be that I am thinking in wrong direction all together.

Please give me some insight into the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate why a store procedure is not an option?

Comment: I have got different copies of database already and hence would need to have stored procedure on each one. Hence, I want to develop an independent system completely program based to perform the task.

Comment: Are you doing more than just running a few queries from your program?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but if you can execute a stored procedure from an SSIS package, then what problem are you having executing 'normal' SQL? And you haven't explained why you're "struggling" or "stuck": what specific problems or errors do you have?

Comment: well as long as you can execute stuff you can also write a query string  from a programing language that will create a store preocedure on the server or just have scripts saved somewhere and just execute them via a connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear, the *only* execute method within Dts.Runtime is at the Package level. You don't need to call ExecuteSQLTask.Execute (no such thing, by the way) or anything in your C#.

Just build up your package's Executables, and then execute the package (or save it or whatever you want to do with it.) HINT: Use the SqlCommand property of the ExecuteSQLTask to set your command query from your program.

You'll also probably want to look into [EzApi](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/21238) which makes building packages programmatically in C# a lot easier.